Make a copy of a pandas series whose elements contain class objects and update only the copy
I am trying to create a copy of a pandas series whose elements contain instances of a given class. I do so with the following command
duplicateSeries = originalSeries.copy()

Now, when i go to make changes in the elements of the duplicateSeries, such as changes in a series within a class instance, the corresponding elements of the originalSeries also gets updated.
How can I prevent this from happening?

see Notes in the docs about deep copying Python objects

The objects inside both the original and the copied Series still reference the same memory location (so the same objects).
To solve it just create a deepcopy, that copy not only the Series structure but the objects inside:
import copy

duplicateSeries = originalSeries.apply(copy.deepcopy)

